# Template Button GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, web

I'm using a GridView in my web application and converted the default delete/edit buttons to template fields. I did this because I can't simply delete users from the database with the default SQL delete query that was generated.

I want to use Membership.DeleteUser() however I don't know how to get the username from the GridView that corresponds to the LinkButton that the user presses.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass value in `CommandArgument` and get it in the code behind.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                
      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnDelete"
        Text="Delete"
        CommandName="Delete"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

You can also use `DataKeyNames="UserName"` in your gridview and get it in code behind.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. `Membership.DeleteUser(e.CommandArgument)
        Response.Write(Request.RawUrl.ToString())`, this is how I get the argument in the code behind. I've tried passing `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName") %>''`and `CommandArgument="@userName"`

Comment: To anyone wondering, I ended up using `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'` to get the Item's Index and then using that found out the text of the cell.